# Button click event error for toast on android studio

Tags: java, android

This code does not run on Android Studio. I just want it to display a toast when the button is clicked. Please help. Code is attached below:

I'm new to android development and is having a hard time figuring this out. I think the problem is a silly syntax error or variable not being defined. Also, how do I define "v" ?

```
package com.shutter2000.www.shutter_2000_oms;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    


public class SiteVisitDetails extends Activity {

public EditText mCusName;
public EditText mOrderID;
public EditText mProjectID;
public EditText mHeightWidth;
public EditText mNote;
public Button mSubmitButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_site_visit_details);

    //initialize text fields
    mCusName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCusName);
    mOrderID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtOrderID);
    mProjectID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProjectID);
    mHeightWidth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHeightWidth);
    mNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNote);
    mSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    //listen to submit button click event

    mSubmitButton.OnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){


        if (v == mSubmitButton) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Successfully Sent!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            final Toast tost = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            tost.show();
        }
    }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.site_visit_details, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addItemsToProductSpinner() {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnProducts);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.products, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Errors are:

Errors for "mSubmitButton..."

```
Expected class or package
'OnClickListener' is abstract;cannot be instantiated
```

Errors for "@override public void onClick(View v){..."

```
Annotations are not allowed here
Identifier or type expected
```

Errors for "public void addItemsToProductSpinner()..."

```
";" expected
Cannot resolve symbol "v"
unexpected token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.shutter2000.www.shutter_2000_oms;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    


public class SiteVisitDetails extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public EditText mCusName;
public EditText mOrderID;
public EditText mProjectID;
public EditText mHeightWidth;
public EditText mNote;
public Button mSubmitButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_site_visit_details);

    //initialize text fields
    mCusName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCusName);
    mOrderID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtOrderID);
    mProjectID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProjectID);
    mHeightWidth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHeightWidth);
    mNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNote);
    mSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    //listen to submit button click event

    mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     if (v.getId() == R.id.mSubmitButton) {
         Toast.makeText(this,"Successfully sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
     }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.site_visit_details, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addItemsToProductSpinner() {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnProducts);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.products, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: you should mention the id of your button in xml file. for example if id of your button in xml file is btn_submit. then you have to check v.getId()==R.id.btn_submit

Comment: ya, my mistake, it should be in capital case i.e. LENGTH_LONG

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong `v == mSubmitButton`
In java, can equals with operator == only primitive types. For object you need use equals() method.
Replace:

```
mSubmitButton.onClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){


        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSubmit) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Successfully Sent!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            final Toast tost = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            tost.show();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to check

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

 //Don't need to check condition control come here only v.getId() == R.id.btnSubmit 
   //  if (v == mSubmitButton) { 

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Successfully Sent!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        final Toast tost = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        tost.show();
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 mSubmitButton.OnClickListener(
```

should be

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(
```

Edit. The method setOnClickListener expects an object that implements the `View.OnClickListener` interface:

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Successfully Sent!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        final Toast tost = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        tost.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Both gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.btnSubmit){
     Toast.makeText(SiteVisitDetails.this,"Successfully Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        CharSequence text = "Successfully Sent!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast tost = Toast.makeText(SiteVisitDetails.this, text, duration);
        tost.show();
    }

});
```

Use this. No need to check `if(v.getId() == R.id.btnSubmit)`. Because you are setting a click action to an already initiliazed button.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the setter to set an onclickListener. 
And as you are using a new onclicklistener and you are only setting it for your button, you dont need to check if v==mSubmitButton because it's the only choice anyway :)

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Successfully Sent!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            final Toast tost = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            tost.show();

    }
```

Comment: nice to hear it fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'this' with getApplicationContext()

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 if (v.getId() == R.id.mSubmitButton) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully sent!",Toast.Length_LONG).show();             
 }

}
```

Comment: That gives the error:

"OnClickListener" is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: setOnClickListner is also abstract function
use studio intelligence. i hope that method will be there too.

Comment: @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully sent!",Toast.Length_LONG).show();             
     }

}

Answer (score 0):

To display a toast when the button is clicked.

```
    mSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //SiteVisitDetails
            Toast tea = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            tea.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is misplaced parenthesis in your syntax, and a missing `;` and a misspelled `setOnClickListener` method name.

Change

```
mSubmitButton.OnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
    {
    // ...
    }
```

to

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    // ...
    });
```